# MySQL query uses too much CPU

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, query-optimization

I use the following query to find users that I need to send daily reminders based on their settings and timezone. It works but turned up that it uses about 50% CPU and its really heavy even when I add Limit 0,100.

(It even causes phpMyAdmin to crash or something)

Users table: 3000 records,
Posts table: 12000+ records,
Settings table: 3000 records,
Reminders table: 80000 records (Keeps user_id and date to prevent duplicates)

```
   SELECT u.`id`, u.`fullname`, u.`email`, u.`hash`, s.`timezone`
   FROM `users` u
   LEFT JOIN `reminders` rm ON rm.`user_id` = u.`id` AND rm.`date` = CURDATE()
   LEFT JOIN `settings` s ON s.`user_id` = u.`id`
   LEFT JOIN `posts` p ON p.`user_id` = u.`id` AND p.`date` = DATE(CONVERT_TZ(UTC_TIMESTAMP, 'UTC', s.`timezone`))
   WHERE HOUR(CONVERT_TZ(UTC_TIMESTAMP, 'UTC', s.`timezone`)) = s.`notify_hour`
   AND s.`notify` = 1 AND u.`active` = 1 AND rm.`id` IS NULL AND p.`id` IS NULL
   GROUP BY u.`id` LIMIT 0,100
```

I run this query every 10 minutes and I'm sending reminders through sendgrid.com SMTP server.
Can you please help me optimize this query so that it doesn't use this much resource?

Thank you (and sorry for my English)

Comment: First place to start - look at the index strategy on all of those "id" fields.

Comment: JetProfiler if you have the resources - http://www.jetprofiler.com/

Comment: I would also look at adding active to your index too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have the fields properly indexed? 
here is a suggestion:

Try to index the user_id field on all the tables it should make it faster.

Also the conversion of dates is eating up the cpu time, you should store the dates in UTC format in your database this way you will avoid a huge overhead

Comment: the "Users" table column name is "id" rest are "user_id". Is it ok?

Comment: Yes, naming does not matter - the indexes matter.

Comment: the naminng is not an issue, i actually think its a good naming convention. have you tried indexing those fields?

Comment: Showing rows 0 - 29 ( 100 total, Query took 0.0082 sec)
Its fast right?